# Potentiometer's working

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[image]
I know that in a closed circuit with multiple batteries, current is provided by the battery which has the maximum voltage.

Let's suppose that $E \gt V$. Now, the voltage $V_b$ at point $b$ will always be $V$ and will not depend on $E$.

Similarly the voltage $V_A$ at point $A$ is $V-E$ which will be negative in order to make potential difference across the galvanometer wire equal to $V$.

My question is that why, at point $b$, $E$ has no effect on $V_b$?

Also, is it true that if $E>V$ then the current will be supplied by $E$ and not $V$?

Take potential at C =0

Comment: *"Now the potential at point B will always be V"* - (1) to specify a voltage at node $b$, you need to specify the node with zero volts (the common or 'ground' node).  (2) assuming the 'ground' node is the negative terminal of the top-most cell, the voltage at node $b$ is V only if the current *I* is zero *or* if the rheostat is set to zero ohms.  That is, $V_b = V - I\cdot R_{Rh}$

Comment: "I know that in a closed circuit with multiple batteries, current is provided by the battery which has the maximum voltage". How do you know that?

Comment: @BobD i read it on quora that the battery with max voltage provides the current until the voltage of battery are equal

Comment: @Who That sounds like the case where voltages oppose one another, such as two batteries with a resistor  connected between them. But if you have one battery of voltage $V$ directly connected across a resistor $R$, that battery will deliver a current equal to $\frac{V}{R}$ regardless of the presence of other batteries in other parts of the circuit.

Comment: @BobD, to be clear, that battery will deliver a current equal to $\frac{V}{R}$ *to that resistor* regardless of the presence (...)  but the *total* current through that battery isn't necessarily independent of other parts of the circuit.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes that is correct. I was only trying to point out that it is not only the battery with the maximum voltage that delivers current, which is what I thought the OP was inferring.

Comment: @BobD  "resistor connected between them" what's if there is no resistor ,will the current be still provided by the battery of maximum emf?